# C++ Looping through objects and pointers with the same code

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

So I have two containers

```
set<Person>
vector<Person*>
```

Is there any way for the following transform lambda code to be modified such that either container can be used?

```
transform(container.begin(), container.end(), back_inserter(data),
          [](const Person* p) { return PairResults(p->getTime(), p->getName()); }
);
```

Right now I'm only able to get it to work on the vector.

Thanks.

### >> [Solution Code Here](http://ideone.com/X3XWVz)

Many thanks to Andrew for his help on this one!

Comment: This is very doubtful, because the operators for dealing with pointers and objects are different.

Comment: @merlin2011, I know, but I figured it was worth asking. I was hoping using a reference would work, but it didn't.

Comment: I hope someone will prove me wrong. :)

Comment: Using Boost.Range's `boost::adaptors::indirected` would be a simple idea.

Comment: @Xeo, can't use boost (HW). Never heard of deref, got an example or tutorial link that shows what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry the `deref` stuff would only work for C++14 with generic lambdas, unfortunately.

Comment: @Xeo so no other way? If MSVS supports it, I might be able to get away with it.

Comment: You could just write a functor manually, with overloaded `operator()` on pointer and reference.

Comment: @Xeo, I know, it just seems such a waist that I have to do that to change four characters, especially when the function that holds the transform is already a template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a *proxy object* that accepts pointer to Person or ref to Person and gives them both pointer semantics:

Live example: http://ideone.com/Wk2VMx

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Person {
    int age;
    std::string name;
};

class PersonProxy {
    public:
        PersonProxy(Person& p)
        : person(&p) {}
        PersonProxy(Person* p)
        : person(p) {}

        Person& operator*() { return *person; }
        Person* operator->() { return person; }

    private:
        Person* person;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> p1;
    p1.push_back(Person{42, "Bob"});

    Person bill{30, "Bill"};
    std::set<Person*> p2;
    p2.insert(&bill);

    std::vector<int> data;

    auto the_lambda = [](PersonProxy pp) {return pp->age;};

    std::transform(p1.begin(), p1.end(), std::back_inserter(data), the_lambda);
    std::transform(p2.begin(), p2.end(), std::back_inserter(data), the_lambda);

    for (int age : data)
    {
        std::cout << age << "\n";
    }

}
```

Another approach would be to use a functor instead of the lambda, and define `operator()(Person&)` and `operator()(Person*)`, but the approach above is to provide a type with which you can write the lambdas, and for which implicit conversions from `Person` and `Person*` are available.

Comment: You have the implicit part, and that I like. There's no way to keep it all in one class though by overloading the main parent?

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid providing implicit conversions between `T*` and `T&`. This approach means you can only get the implicit conversions in situations where you _explicitly_ request them - by taking a PersonProxy argument! Of course, you could do this if you wanted, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: What would be some of the potential fallbacks of it being implicit?

Comment: I don't really have a list, but some things that come to mind include the possibility that a pointer can be null, while a reference can't (so how do you handle implicit conversion of null pointer to a reference?), and that you can hold a const reference to an rvalue, but not a pointer to one. I suppose if you have a valid object and you provide `operator Person*()` then you're reasonably safe; you just return `this`. Still, I would avoid such type gymnastics and stick with the much safer proxy object. Implicit conversions have a way of tripping you up when you least expect it.

Comment: Okay, I converted your code to a template, and then did some adjustments of what I'm actually doing. Now it's erroring. Any ideas? http://ideone.com/X3XWVz

Comment: @David Yes, you need to either remove the `const` in your lambda param, or add a constructor taking const T& to the proxy. It is complaining that it cannot convert from a const T to a Proxy<T>&.

Comment: Hmm, thought I tried that. Oh well, many thanks, working like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using a little trick with function overload: define two functions that produce a pointer to `Person`, like this:

```
const Person* make_ptr(const Person* p) { return p; }
const Person* make_ptr(const Person& p) { return &p; }
```

The next problem is unifying the type of the element for the lambda: unfortunately, it is not legal to say `[](auto p) {...}` and let the compiler pick `Person` or `Person*` for you. Using a template solves this problem:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
void xform(vector<T>& from, vector<R>& to) {
    transform(from.begin(), from.end(), back_inserter(to),
        [&](T &p) { return PairResults(make_ptr(p)->getTime(), make_ptr(p)->getName()); }
    );
}
```

Now everything works - you can call `xform` with a container of `Person` or `Person*`, and get the correct results.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/s9XLj0)

Comment: Unfortunately, now you have to create a wrapper template for each stdlib algorithm you might want to call.

Comment: Is there a way to encapsulate this idea into my class with implicit conversion? Because right now, my error is "No known conversion from const Person* to const Person&"

Comment: @Andrew Not really - OP's function is already a template ([see this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093695/c-looping-through-objects-and-pointers-with-the-same-code/25093902?noredirect=1#comment39047029_25093695)) so he wouldn't need to write `xform` if `Person` or `Person*` is already a template type parameter.

Comment: @David This is likely related to `const`-ness of the pointer. You may want to add another function `const Person* make_ptr(const Person* p) { return p; }` which should work, assuming that `getTime` and `getName` are marked `const` as well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, both are const, and if I change to a reference and a dot operator, the lambda works perfectly.

Comment: @David I edited to deal with `const`-ness. I also changed the demo.

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like the following will work

```
   template <class T> struct MakePair {
      PairResults operator () (const T & p) {
         return PairResults(p.getTime(), p.getName());
      }
   };

   template <class T> struct MakePair<T*> {
      PairResults operator () (const T * p) {
         return PairResults(p->getTime(), p->getName());
      }
   };

   typedef decltype (* (container.begin ())) container_element_type;

   transform(container.begin(), container.end(), back_inserter(data),
          [] (const container_element_type & p) {
              return MakePair<container_element_type> {} (p);
          }
   );
```

In my opinion, the fact that it is difficult to achieve what you require is a sign of some missing abstraction in your code.

Who, for instance, is responsible for disposing the heap-allocated objects in your vector?

Consider hiding the implementation details of your container behind a `PersonContainer` with a well-defined interface.